# Remote certificate rejected when connecting to SQL Server from Linux host

Tags: c#, sql-server, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have been provided a certificate for a SQL Server, which has been successfully installed and activated. I can confirm this from the logs:

```
The certificate [Cert Hash(sha1) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxE5C050F7D75F58E4E2F"] was successfully loaded for encryption.
```

Connecting to the database using SSMS is successful, simply by encrypting the connection without trusing the server certificate.

I wanted to replicate this using WSL and later on - docker.

I am testing this with a simple .net 6 console application:

```cs
var con = new SqlConnection("Server=domain.host.eu,50730;Database=databasename;User Id=user;Password='password';");
await con.OpenAsync();
var version = con.ExecuteScalar<string>("SELECT @@VERSION");
Console.WriteLine(version);
```

This works, if I add `Trust Server Certificate=True;` to the connection string. Without it, the connection fails:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
```

I wanted to extract the certificate from the pfx:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in host.domain.eu.pem.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out host.domain.eu.crt
sudo cp host.domain.eu.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Unfortunately, this fails with the same error messages and I don't know where I went wrong. I can only assume, that my handling of the certs on Linux is wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at these issues: [#1535](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1535) and [#1402](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1402)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have, but unfortunately they do not offer a viable / working solution, except to trust the server certificate

Comment: Also the certificate must meet [some requirements to be considered valid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189067(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Cleptus, I know that it is working, by testing it from a Windows machine using SSMS and verifying from the logs, that the cert was loaded.

Comment: So what steps did you do to add it in to SQL Server on Linux?

Comment: The server stays the same. The connection fails from linux, steps as described above.

Comment: But who issues the certificate and how do you trust the issuer?

Comment: It's our internal it department. I have to draw the line somewhere. So I trust the certificates I get from them.

Comment: So it's not a new/different self-signed certificate then? Did you add your IT department's CA and ICA certificates to the ca-certificates store on linux?

Comment: I've tried that too, yes @AlwaysLearning. Unfortunately the error stayed the same. And no, it's not a self signed certificate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I double blindsided myself and got distracted by 2 mishaps at the same time.

After importing a certificate into the SQL Configuration Manager, you can choose from 2 nigh on identical entries. The difference beeing one having a friendly name of `host.domain` (FQDN), while the other has no friendly name.
Naturally I have not double checked and just stayed with the one without the FQDN as the friendly name, which was pre-selected after the import and looked valid.
The second mistake was to not realize, that WSL was not part of our domain and could not resolve the database name. So I used to the FQDN to reach it. This caused the mismatch between `host`, which the database instance expected and `host.domain`, which the client from inside WSL used.

After this I borrowed an Ubuntu vm inside our domain and verified, that using only the `host,port` schema in the connection string works.

And to make it explicit *and* work inside wsl I switched the certificates around to require the FQDN as the friendly namae while connecting, so connections can be made from inside the domain, as well as "outside" (from wsl).

**tl;dr**: One possible explanation for the exception `The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.` is, that the instance name in the connection string and the expected name from the instance do not match.

Comment: possible solution: [How to solve 'Cannot authenticate using Kerberos' issue doing EF Core database scaffolding in Linux(Ubuntu 18.04)? Are there any solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62467563/12743268)  it worked for me.

Answer (score 34):

If you're connecting to something unimportant, I was experiencing this error connecting from my dotnetcore API, to a microsoft sql server contained in a docker container (all locally) for dev work. My solution was putting `encrypt=False` at the end of my connection string like so (within appsettings.json):

`"DefaultConnection":  "server=localhost;database=newcomparer;trusted_connection=false;User Id=sa;Password=reallyStrongPwd123;Persist Security Info=False;Encrypt=False"`

Comment: Encrypt False is an utterly wrong solution, as I wouldn't be using certificates, if I wanted to not encrypt the connection.

Comment: I don't totally disagree with you, but my googling looking for a solution brought me here, I found a solution to my simple dev environment problem and decided to share the solution for others...

Comment: FYI: It is not working for me, a nice exception was thrown by kerberos.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot authenticate using Kerberos. Ensure Kerberos has been initialized on the client with 'kinit' and a Service Principal Name has been registered for the SQL Server to allow Kerberos authentication.
ErrorCode=InternalError, Exception=Interop+NetSecurityNative+GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.

Comment: encrypt=False was needed by FluentMigration version 5 that released on 12/10/2023.