# Docker SQL-Server login problem: AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm working on a Docker related application, written in C#, based on Entity Framework.

One of the Docker containers, is the ms-sql-server, which is used for database access.
In order to access the SQL-server, following `connectionString` is created:

```
Server=ms-sql-server;Initial Catalog=Ownobjects;User ID=SA;Password=some_password
```

While performing following source code:

```
public void InitialiseDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  using (var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
  {
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    ...
```

... I get following `Exception`:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server,
  but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.
  (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)'  

Inner Exception  
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected
  by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
```

According to [this similar StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72087048), two things might not match: the instance name in the connection string and the expected name from the instance.

1. Is this true? In that case, where or how can I find both names?
2. If this is not true, then what might be causing this issue?

**Edit:**
Some further examination:
In the Logs of the `ms-sql-server` Docker container, I've found following line:

```
Server name is 'e614890825ac'.
This is an informational message only.
No user action is required
```

I've used this entry in the `connectionString` but then the same  `Exception` is raised, but this time with following `Inner Exception:`:

```
ExtendedSocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

**Edit2:**
Again some further examination:
In the meantime I've discovered that my original servername in the `connectionString` is correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nobody has an idea?

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and in explorer check logs under Management.  The SSMS login window should show same server\instance as in the connection string.  The login window should show Window credentials and then the connection string should have Integrated Security = true (no username and password).

Comment: @jdweng: Thanks for your quick reply, but I'm working in a Docker environment, which has some different rules than regular SQL-server.

Comment: There is authentication and credentials.  Still you need to check the SQL Logs to help isolate issues.  If you do not see a failure in the logs than the issue is in docker.  If you do see the error in the logs than error will indicate exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Recent versions of `SqlClient` now default to having encryption on, rather than off. If this is the issue, and assuming you don't actually need an encrypted connection between your host and your container (which doesn't add much) adding `Encrypt=false` to your connection string should prevent issues with certificate checks (if you do explicitly want to have an encrypted connection, things get more complicated).

Comment: Heu... there are no logs: I mean the logfile is there, but when I launch my application, nothing has been added to the logs: neither the logs of Microsoft SQL-Server Management Studio, neither the ms-sql-server Docker container.

Comment: have you solved this issue? could you share your Dockerfile (client) or the image that the client uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent some time solving this message `SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake`

**Solution 1 (Encryption in client container):**

Dockerfile client [(github issue)](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/633)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
# ...

# SQL Server trusted connection problem
RUN sed -i 's/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

# ...
```

Note: There's no need to change your connection string adding Encrypt=false or anything else with this setting

Note 2: I'have tried to use focal and other linux images and only aspnet:6.0 works with this setting.

**Solution 2 (Image version or storage problems):**

- Change the runtime version of the client container (see github comments)
- Replace the binding storage or volume in sql server container. This could be a user access problem.

Note: There are some comments about [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1446)

Answer (score 20):

Adding the following to the client's connection string solved it for me:

`;TrustServerCertificate=true`